# Movie with a girl/fairy who was talking to a unicorn in a snow covered forest

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie some time in what was probably 2010 or 11 on Netflix. I keep randomly remembering it and every time I search for it, I can't find it. I don't know what it was called, but I remember a bit about the movie itself.

I remember there was a girl (may or may not have been a fairy) who was talking to a unicorn (or was it a pegasus? or both? maybe even just a magical horse?) in the middle of a forest with snow. I believe they were talking about how the unicorns were in danger and needed someone to take care of their child. Then the girl wakes up in her bed and at the end of her bed the baby unicorn looks up at her from under a blanket. *insert magical adventure to find the unicorns parents* I think by the end of their little adventure whatever villain there probably was has been defeated and the unicorns can live back in their magical unicorn palace.

Comment: Just watched this recently, give me a moment to find it.

Comment: Was it a live-action movie, or was it animated? Because it sounds an awful lot like a movie from the 1980s called "Legend". The unicorns, girl, fairies, forest with snow, unicorns being in danger, and villain all seem to check out, but the details don't match up 100%.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - it's animated, recent.  Not Legend.  Trying to find it in my history now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [Princess Lillifee and the Little Unicorn](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1986935/).  It's a German animated film that came out in 2011, and appears to have been shown through a few streaming sites since (currently over at Amazon).

Princess Lillifee is a fairy princess of Pinkovia, and does receive a dream from a unicorn to look after her child, after which the child is magically there on waking.  They do set off to find the unicorn's parents, and end up in a magically frozen kingdom that has been taken over by a childish prince.

Trying to remember the rest of it as there's not much online about it, but the gist is once in the frozen kingdom, Lillifee's magic won't work anymore (the sparkles just freeze).  The little unicorn's horn can grant wishes, but Lillifee doesn't want to abuse that power, as it's prone to backfiring and the little one's limited understanding of what's going on.  The prince of the frozen kingdom has been abusing a magically bound servant's power to freeze anything to encase all of his rivals, which happened to include the unicorn's parents.  There's some chasing and silliness from there.

Little more googling, turns out there's two Lillifee movies, both based on a series of German children's books by Monika Finsterbusch.